# Can't get floated menu to center

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a floated menu at the top of the page, but it wont center.
I used the code from here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxgoj
and this is mine: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BDpte

```
<body>
<div id="header">
</div>
<div id="content">
<div id="main">
</div>
</div>
<div class="navigation">
<div class="navigation.fixer">
<ul class="floating-elements">
<li class="floated"><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
<li class="floated"><a href="Joeys.html">Joeys</a></li>
<li class="floated"><a href="Cubs.html">Cubs</a></li>
<li class="floated"><a href="Scouts.html">Scouts</a></li>
<li class="floated"><a href="Venturers.html">Venturers</a></li>
<li class="floated"><a href="Rovers.html">Rovers</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
</div>
</body>

@charset "utf-8";

.navigation {
float:left;
position:relative;
left:50%;
/*overflow:hidden;*/
}

.navigation.fixer {
float:left;
position:relative;
left:-50%;
}

.floating-elements
{
list-style:none;
}

.floated
{
float:left; margin-right:10px;
}
```

Help would be much appreciated.. :)

Comment: simply replace `navigation.fixer` with `navigation fixer` in your code

Comment: Once I add more content how do I make sure the menu stays at the top?

Answer (score 0):

```
.navigation {
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
}

.floated {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/otbmtf13/

Answer (score 0):

I have solution here : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tJaHy

For elements with class names containing a period '.' in them, you should escape the period while specifying the css handle like so

```
.navigation\.fixer{
.....
}
```

else the regular css handling means a string of type ".navigation.fixer"  is an element having both distinct class names of "navigation" and "fixer" , which is not the case here as it is a single class name.